# Atomic updates of Azure Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I know that in Azure Table Storage, it's possible to update two entries in a row atomically.  Is it possible to update the content + metadata of Azure Blobs atomically?

If I do

```
blob.Metadata["field"] = "helloworld"
blob.UploadFromStream(stream,accessCondition)
```

Will that update atomically? (read, if "helloworld" is present, am I guaranteed that the content of blob will be the stream?

Comment: Do you mean, whether both metadata and content will either update or fail simultaneously? Please clarify.

Comment: Assuming no failures, is there any way I'll be able to see just "helloworld" but not the new stream, or the new stream but not "helloworld"

Comment: Do you mean, you just want to fetch metadata but not the actual blob data (in stream) and vice versa?

Comment: No, I want to, in one go, upload the stream and the metadata, so that I have the guarantee that both "helloworld" and the new stream will be present

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question is yes, both metadata and stream will be present.

Basically when you do this:

```
blob.Metadata["field"] = "helloworld"
```

No network call is being made. This property is stored in `blob` object.

```
blob.UploadFromStream(stream,accessCondition)
```

The line above actually makes the network call and sets the blob content and metadata in blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Block Blob, you can call Put Block to upload content firstly, and then call Put Block List to commit blob content and metadata by one request.